# How We check file or folder in dropbox v2

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I check file or folder from main routes in dropbox api v2 
i am trying through this method

### my code in obj c

```
DBUserClient *client = [DBClientsManager authorizedClient];

//NSString *searchPath = @"";
// "Full Dropbox" or "/Apps/<APP_NAME>/" if app has permission "App Folder").
[[client.filesRoutes listFolder:path]
 setResponseBlock:^(DBFILESListFolderResult *result, DBFILESListFolderError *routeError, DBRequestError *networkError) {
     if (result) {
         [self displayPhotos:result.entries];

     } else {

         NSString *title = @"";
         NSString *message = @"";
         if (routeError) {
             // Route-specific request error
             title = @"Route-specific error";
             if ([routeError isPath]) {
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invalid path: %@", routeError.path];
             }
         } else {
             // Generic request error
             title = @"Generic request error";
             if ([networkError isInternalServerError]) {
                 DBRequestInternalServerError *internalServerError = [networkError asInternalServerError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", internalServerError];
             } else if ([networkError isBadInputError]) {
                 DBRequestBadInputError *badInputError = [networkError asBadInputError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", badInputError];
             } else if ([networkError isAuthError]) {
                 DBRequestAuthError *authError = [networkError asAuthError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", authError];
             } else if ([networkError isRateLimitError]) {
                 DBRequestRateLimitError *rateLimitError = [networkError asRateLimitError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", rateLimitError];
             } else if ([networkError isHttpError]) {
                 DBRequestHttpError *genericHttpError = [networkError asHttpError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", genericHttpError];
             } else if ([networkError isClientError]) {
                 DBRequestClientError *genericLocalError = [networkError asClientError];
                 message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", genericLocalError];
             }
         }

         UIAlertController *alertController =
         [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                             message:message
                                      preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyle)UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
         [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                             style:(UIAlertActionStyle)UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                           handler:nil]];
         [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

         //[self setFinished];
     }
 }];
```

the above codes showing the result in DBFILESListFolderResult and i save into `NSArray<DBFILESListFolderResult *> *arr`
Now in result shows .tag=file/folder but cant get in variable please help me how we get this tag and save in variable
now my results is ## Result ##

```
{
cursor = "AAG_UmQvZ1am1-D_sQ9Vu7rufWd2JQ8GNNk16EDpcKW5PtUuhpzJTZhNoTPIPQ3-_clzcJh2ixtkEqy_8rMzpLyumkgu851X3752-NczhJiTpp0t-lWSme20htOgCVso9l_1tbjf-jBJEEB2JxSdeHlu7byifT74fT7EepYRO7Si4FQcUHSDoGhTsGHV3rGuqFU";
entries =     (
            {
        ".tag" = folder;
        id = "id:qPwKdoK_nCAAAAAAAAAABg";
        name = "IPA File";
        "path_display" = "/IPA File";
        "path_lower" = "/ipa file";
        "shared_folder_id" = 1493424685;
        "sharing_info" =             {
            "no_access" = 0;
            "read_only" = 0;
            "shared_folder_id" = 1493424685;
            "traverse_only" = 0;
        };
    },
            {
        ".tag" = folder;
        id = "id:qPwKdoK_nCAAAAAAAAC2pA";
        name = ali;
        "path_display" = "/ali";
        "path_lower" = "/ali";
    },
            {
        ".tag" = file;
        "client_modified" = "2017-10-17T06:56:43Z";
        "content_hash" = a266bbb3f8a11c095fbe4a94647df343dbede5d90635065b5ae84e96d937d3bb;
        id = "id:qPwKdoK_nCAAAAAAAAC2mA";
        name = "OpenHouseID.zip";
        "path_display" = "/OpenHouseID.zip";
        "path_lower" = "/openhouseid.zip";
        rev = 155f1577317c2;
        "server_modified" = "2017-10-17T08:15:35Z";
        size = 354077251;
    },
            {
        ".tag" = file;
        "client_modified" = "2017-10-17T06:55:21Z";
        "content_hash" = f8fa98bdcb232ca9040feeb16ea25fb4a355c061a2c275eedb48eacfa98bc909;
        id = "id:qPwKdoK_nCAAAAAAAAC2mQ";
        name = "Latest With PushNotifications.zip";
        "path_display" = "/Latest With PushNotifications.zip";
        "path_lower" = "/latest with pushnotifications.zip";
        rev = 155f2577317c2;
        "server_modified" = "2017-10-17T09:43:52Z";
        size = 375600989;
    }
       );
    "has_more" = 0;
}
```

Comment: There are examples showing how to distinguish the subclasses of `Metadata` (file/folder/deleted) using `isKindOfClass` [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#response-handling-edge-cases) and [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#rpc-style-request). Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot now how we can set images for folder and file types
like abc.png is file and there image type shows that its image.....
like abc is folder and there image type shows that its folder

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Please make a new post with details if you have a new question or problem.